# How to add custom select all checkbox in toolbar using mui datagrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datagrid

I am currently using mui data grid to create my table. The properties are as follows

```
   <DataGrid
              rows={serialsList || []}
              columns={columns}
              rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 100]}
              //pageSize={93}
              checkboxSelection={this.state.cancelShipFlag ? true : false}
              disableSelectionOnClick={false}
              components={{
                Toolbar: NewToolbar,
              }}
              onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
                const selectedIDs = new Set(ids);
                console.log('Selected ID ' + selectedIDs);
                const selectedRows = rowData.filter((row) => selectedIDs.has(row.id));

                this.setState({ rowinfo: selectedRows });
                console.log(selectedRows);
              }}
              
            />
```

I want to create a custom select All checkbox in the toolbar which selects all the rows in the table upon selection. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can change your checkbox like this :

```
<DataGrid
  loading={loading}
  pagination
  checkboxSelection
  isRowSelectable={isRowSelectable as SclTableProps['isRowSelectable']}
  columns={columns as SclTableProps['columns']}
  rows={rows}
  selectionModel={selectionModel}
  components={{
    BaseCheckbox: (a) => loading ? <>loading...</> : (
        <Checkbox checked={a.checked} /> // <-- this is imported from '@material-ui'
      ),
    }}
/>
```

but I don't suggest you do this why? cause, when you use the custom checkbox in the data grid  check box, lost its own functionality and you must write all logic by yourself